# How to allow Deno to follow redirects when installing scripts?

Tags: deno

This doesn't work:

```sh
deno install -n testdeno https://gist.github.com/raw/b1d7c6a2617a40d092f6fa5e055ac748
```

I'm getting error:

```sh
error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module.
  Specifier: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raw/b1d7c6a2617a40d092f6fa5e055ac748
  MediaType: Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not redirection problem, but the url has to have file name, i.e.:

```sh
deno install -n testdeno https://gist.github.com/raw/b1d7c6a2617a40d092f6fa5e055ac748/test.ts
```

Both urls are doing redirects, and both of them show the same file.